# Synchronizing database between local and remote machines

Tags: sync, remote, database, cloud-storage

This may be a popular question, But i am new to synchronization concept. Please guide me with suggestions.

My requirement is to have a local and remote database(cloud) to sync the data between them. I am creating a mobile app and desktop app to access the same database for data sync. But mobile and desktop app will have a local database similar to the database schema which is running in remote in case of no internet connectivity. When internet connectivity happens, the changes made in local database has to sync with remote database or vice versa. I am developing the desktop application in Javafx and mobile app in iOS and Android in Objective C and Java respectively.

How can i achieve this database synchronization?

When i googled, i found that database replication works for this scenario. I am thinking of using Couchdb for both remote and local database. Will Couchdb supports this type of database synchronization?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24234320/couchdb-online-offline-synchronisation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most people I have seen using couch, and then remote devices use pouchDB on the remotes. Synching seems pretty easy and almost does the work itself.

Comment: Syncing will happen when we have internet connectivity. In case of no internet for couple of hours, will the changes made in that couple of hours will get sync automatically when internet connectivity comes?